# When to use `equation` over `align`

Tags: equations, amsmath

As far as I can tell,
a single line `align` renders identically to an `equation`.

So on that basis, I have just been using `align` everywhere,
as it makes it easier later if I decide actually I need to add another line to expand out a formula, to enhance the explanation.

Is there any downside to this?

Comment: Your claim --  "As far as I can tell, a single line `align` renders identically to an `equation`" -- is incorrect. *Inter alia*, the amount of vertical whitespace above and below single-line displayed equations of type `equation` and `align` are *not* the same.

Comment: Yes, indeed. So I have learnt from the answers.